# Lombok with IDEA 13: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13, lombok

I have tried using Lombok on Intellij IDEA 13 Ultimate.
However. I get the famous error "cannot find symbol" for all the methods that should have been available when I am using specific annotations for example the once I use as annotations are `@Builder`, `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@Data`.

I have already set my compiler to enable annotation processing and I have looked deeply into it, but with no solution of how to solve it.

Any advice or tips would be nice.

Comment: Have you installed the lombok plugin for IDEA? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317

Comment: jupp. the latest one

Comment: Are you using Maven? Have you made sure that the jar is on the classpath?

Comment: Have you solved it already? It's happening to me too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kind of old question here, but I came across the same problem today. I had to do two things to make it work:

1. Set annotation processing on: `Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation
   Processors`
2. Change from ajc to javac for the project: `Compiler -> Java Compiler`

you of course also need the Lombok plugin.

Comment: If i do this, Lombok works, but aspectJ doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: did that, but i also had to (obviously) install lombok plugin.

Comment: not working for me , having same error :java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class __

Comment: @prashantkute are you able to fix your issue. i am also facing the same

Answer (score 6):

In my case non of methods works. But I found solution for my case.
I needed to add to my Gradle dependencies list of

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
}
```

one more line

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
}
```

With such combination you even don't need enabling *Annotation Processors* from @Vegard answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case apart from enabling Annotation Processing and installing Lombok Plugin I had to rebuild project by **Build -> Rebuild Project**

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Using **maven**, after I add at to my pom.xml  **annotationProcessor** nothing changed. Also I'm installed Lombok plugin at Intelij IDEA.

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: Gracias, I won it's troubble with replaced my project at Default in Settings -> Build -> Annotation Processors and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, but resolved it by upgrading to IDEA 15.0.2 and Lombok plugin 0.9.6.14. I had to restart IDEA several times before all of the getters/setters generated by Lombok were resolved.

I also found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430992/3485639), but it didn't seem to help my problem. It may help you if upgrading does not.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with the @Mike's solution above, and it works.
For your information, even though I enabled the **Annotation Processors** , but it seems like not working.
After I added the **annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'**
it was built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use intellij Idea go to setting and add Lombok plugin to your intellij idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QdZn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in my Gradle project by including the Lombok plugin.
No dependencies or annotationProcessor needed (nor did those work for me).

For example in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "6.5.1"
}
```

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned solutions work perfectly, although there's another instance where Lombok annotation processing can fail:

In Gradle or Maven you can pass an argument/flag to prevent annotation processing:

```
-proc:none
```

Hope this helps someone.

Reference: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1449