# IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve symbol

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite, lombok

i have project that is working on `Spring tool suite`.

Also it is working on `InteliJ IDEA 2016 ultimate`, cause my friend is using it, but he could not help me with my problem.

I have installed `InteliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 Ultimtate` and opened my project.
Then i installed `Lombok`

[image]

And restarted IDEA.

The problem is that IDEA does not resolve many imports that STS does.

[image]

I've tried for example:

1)

- Right click on the code editor
- Hover on Maven and expand
- Click on Reimport

2)

- File | Invalidate Caches

but these options did not help me.
I have occured this problem recently(this week) on 2 PC's.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij and Lombok are not actually good friends. As far as I know, the intellij does not want to support lombok annotations but then, I saw a plugin is developed to meet this requirement. I think, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea) thread will help you.