# Lombok generated equals not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I have the value object:

```
@Embeddable
@Value
public class Delivery{

    public String courier;
    public String trackingNumber;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate deliveryDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate expectedDeliveryDate;    

}
```

And I have tried with `@Data` and `@EqualsAndHAshCode` annotations as well. But even when all the fields have exactly the same value on both objects, `.equals` always returns false. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: please try to build your project and see what lombok generate for you, and please post it

Comment: Right, my problem was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea . But, how can I view what lombok has generated? Did you mean like with the decompiler or so?

Comment: For me, i will config the lombok-plugin in intellij. If you have problem with that, you can just go to your target folder at take a look at the class file, intellij will decompile it for you

Comment: I've closed your question as IIUIC it's solved by an answer there. With intellij things are different (so please add the information to your question the next time), but you can look at what Lombok generates by using `java -jar path/to/lombok.jar -delombok`.

Comment: This's not a duplicate question....