# Lombok + Intellij: cannot resolve method of super class

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I have a superclass

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ErrorResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private String message;
}
```

And I have a child one

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(builderMethodName = "_builder") // add custom builder name to avoid compilation issue 'return type is not compatible...'
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class AskQuestionErrorResponse extends ErrorResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private String status;

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "_builder") // add custom builder name to avoid compilation issue 'return type is not compatible...'
    private AskQuestionErrorResponse(String status, String message){
        super(message);
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

When I use a builder to create an object like this

```
AskQuestionErrorResponse._builder()
   .status(1)
   .message("my message here").build()
```

Intellij shows me `message` in red and there is an issue `cannot resolve method 'message(java.lang.String)'` Anyway project compiles and runs even with this error.

I've already enabled annotations precessing.

If I comment field from superclass like this

```
AskQuestionErrorResponse._builder()
                .status(ex.getStatus().getValue()
                //.message(ex.getMessage()
                ).build()
```

It works. It seems that it does not see superclass members. I've also tried maven clean and install, rebuild project.

UPDATE
Lombok plugin is installed
[image]

Annotation Processors are enabled in `Preferences` and in `Default preferences`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. If you take a look to my class you'll see two `@Builder` annotations. I removed first one and magic happens. Now my class looks like this and there is no warning

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class AskQuestionErrorResponse extends ErrorResponse {
    @JsonProperty
    private String status;

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "_builder") // add custom builder name to avoid compilation issue 'return type is not compatible...'
    public AskQuestionErrorResponse(String status, String message){
        super(message);
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the Intellij Lombok plugin so that it can understand the annotations before the compilation to byte code.
https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij

Comment: It's already installed. `AskQuestionErrorResponse._builder().status(ex.getStatus().getValue()).build()` without field of superclass works perfectly

Comment: There is some additional information here which might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea?rq=1

Comment: There does seem to be a problem with the @Builder annotation though. A possible (but not perfect) work around is discussed here https://reinhard.codes/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/