# ModelMapper returns NULL when trying to map Entity to DTO object

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, modelmapper

Here is the class of the object I am trying to map:

```
package com.agent.module.entities;


import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors
public class Accommodation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String location;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private AccommodationType type;

    private String description;

    private String name;
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Document> images;

    private Integer capacity;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<AdditionalService> additionalServices;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PricePlan> pricePlan;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Agent agent;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="accommodation", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Restriction> restrictions;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Category category;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: "+name+"\n"+"Agent PIB: "+agent.toString()+"\n";
    }

}
```

And here is my DTO object:

```
package com.agent.module.dto;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class AccommodationView {
    private Long id;
    private String location;
    private String typeName;
    private String description;
    private String name;
    private List<String> imagesPath;
    private Integer capacity;
    private List<String> additionalServicesName;
    private List<PricePlanView> pricePlan;
    private String agentUsername;
    private List<RestrictionView> restrictions;
    private String categoryName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: "+id+"\n"+"Type: "+typeName+"\n"+"Description: "+description+"\n"+"Category: "+categoryName+"\n"+"Name: "+name+"\n";
    }

}
```

When I open my Postman and try to get all the `Accommodation` objects from **MySQL** database, I actually want to get DTO objects, and in order to do that I am using `ModelMapper`. But for some reason every time I try to map `Accommodation` to `AccommodationView`, I get Null in return. Here is the class where I am trying to perform the mapping:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/accommodation")
public class AccommodationController {

    @Autowired
    AccommodationRepo accommodationRepo;

    @Autowired 
    ModelMapper mapper;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<List<AccommodationView>> getAll(){
        List<Accommodation> accommodations = accommodationRepo.findAll();

        List<AccommodationView> accommodationViewList= new ArrayList<AccommodationView>();

        for(Accommodation accommodation : accommodations) {
            System.out.println(accommodation);
            System.out.println(convertToDto(accommodation));
            accommodationViewList.add(convertToDto(accommodation));
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<AccommodationView>>(accommodationViewList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private AccommodationView convertToDto(Accommodation accommodation) {
        return mapper.map(accommodation, AccommodationView.class);
    }

    private Accommodation convertToEntity(AccommodationView accommodationView) {
        return mapper.map(accommodationView, Accommodation.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get when I hit the method:

```
Name: Test
Agent PIB: 2308995710368

ID: null
Type: null
Description: null
Category: null
Name: null
```

First part of the output is from `Accommodation` object, and second part of the output is from `AccommodationView` object. If anyone has any idea whats going on I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I haven't used `ModelMapper` before, but I think you need to check the matching strategy: [link](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies).

Answer (score 12):

you have to generate public setters functions for the target class, in your case (Accommodation Entity). elsewise the Modelmapper cannot access the private fields of your class to set their values.

Comment: It is using a lombok `@Getter` `@Setter`, basically generates the setters/getters. Is there a known issue with lombok and model mapper?

Comment: @lemoncodes yes, when you forget these to apply on your class

Comment: I was facing the same problem and was wondering why I get the nulls - seems because I removed the unused getters/setters, thinking that @Builder is enough. Added the getter/setter Lombok annotations, this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two solutions to your problem.

**Solution 1**

In your dto object AccommodationView try to add `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`. Or add for every dto field annotation `@JsonPrperty`. that two ways could help to map dto object and json postman response.

**Solution 2**

Seems that the problem you have is about mapstruct or/and lombok. I would recommand you to check if generated mapper impl mapstruct file ModelMapperImpl looks good (you should have for every entity field an instruction for mapping with dto associated field or/and vice versa).

If this is not the case, check if lombok, mapstruct and lombok-mapstruct-binding deps are well configured in you pom.xml or build.gradle file ( [here an example for this implementation with maven](https://bootify.io/spring-data/mapstruct-with-maven-and-lombok.html) ). Also, For your IDE check if lombok is well configured ([by installing lombok plugins and enabling annotation processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea))