# Lombok not working in intellij idea 18.1 version after importing eclipse gradle spring boot project

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij Idea 18.1 and imported a working Gradle Spring Boot 2.0 project as eclipse model. But trying to build project I get bunch of compile erros related to lombok not being recognised. Gradle clearly defined this dependency as

```
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
```

I get compile errors like:

```
Error:(8, 14) java: package lombok does not exist
```

I followed this Stackoverflow link

[Lombok annotations do not compile under Intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022609/574122)

In IDEA External library has all the jars except lombok jar.

I do not want to install third party lombok plugin and above link made it working without that plugin.

To import gradle spring boot eclipse project, what is the proper way to do it. I may have missed something here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you did.
If the project uses gradle, import it from the gradle model, not from the eclipse model.