# Spring JPA data repository not acting like it should

Tags: java, spring, object, jpa

I am new to `Spring` and I am trying to create an `Object` and add it to my database and then get the value from it. As far as I understand I should not add any extra lines and `findAll` should return me a proper looking `String` as a result. 
But the result I get looks like this:

```
[model.Orders@4a163575, model.Orders@7ecec90d]
```

What I also understood is that I should not add `get/set` methods to `Spring` as they should be automatically generated, but when I try to cast the `model.Orders@4a163575` into an `Object` and do the `get` method It tells me that there is no `get` method.

So here is my `Object`:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Orders {

    public Orders(String orderName) {
        this.orderName = orderName;
    }

    public Orders() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String orderName;

}
```

Then the `findAll` method:

```
@Repository
public class OrderDao {

        public List<Orders> findAll(){
            return em.createQuery("select p from Orders p", Orders.class).getResultList();
        }
}
```

And where I launch it all:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
              new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DbConfig.class);

        OrderDao dao = ctx.getBean(OrderDao.class);

        dao.save(new Orders("order1"));
        dao.save(new Orders("order2"));

        System.out.println(dao.findAll());
}
```

From what I have I think that the `@Data` annotation is not working properly since there is no `toString` nor `getters/setter`.

I import the `@Data` annotation with this line : `import lombok.Data;`.

What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install lombok plugin for that it will be possible generating them

You can refer to this article how to install lombok in IntellijIdea:

[Lombok annotations do not compile under Intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)

Please also add enable annotation processing

Comment: I have it installed by following this : [link](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I had forgotten to `enable annotation processing`.
[Picture to show where and how I did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTbvy.png)