# Lombok Issue In IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have lombok plugin installed on Mac IntelliJ, but for some reason my intelliJ not finding log.info or other logger methods,

i verified the below settings, looks good.

[Lombok annotations do not compile under Intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)

i reinstalled my lombok, and cleared cache and reset it, though no luck.  I have re-installed IntelliJ.

I've cleared few setting under "~/Library/Preferences" too. Not working any suggestion?

Comment: This is the reason I stopped using Lombok. Sometimes it just doesn't work even though everything seems setup

Comment: Make sense Arnaud! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my intelliJ creates main.iml and test.iml after import. After removing those files, works fine. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I primarily use Lombok for auto generating the getters,setters, toString etc. Even though you have downloaded it as a plugin, have you imported it in your pom.xml if you are using Maven project?

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I use Gradle and It was working fine yesterday. For some reasons not working from the Morning. I installed fresh IntelliJ after clear cache, preferences, and other stuff.

Comment: Strange. Which version are you referring to in Gradle?

Comment: The Gradle version is 6.0.1