# cannot find symbol method get/set in Gradle project Intellij Idea

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, get, lombok

I have a Gradle project on Java with Lombok module installed. All fields have @Getter/@Setter annotation, and if I click on any of get/set methods, they will lead me to those fields. But whenever I try to run or build project I get an error "cannot find symbol method get/set".

I tried to invalidate cache, didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok annotations do not compile under Intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)

Comment: Did you add these in your gradle file ? `dependencies {
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'  
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}`

Comment: Its usually a good practice to share the gradle file along with the question and it will help others to answer your question

Comment: @LêHoàngDững I've tried, didn't help

Comment: Do you have "Lombok" plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, go to settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle
And select `Intellij IDEA` for both `Build and run using:` and `Run tests using:`
That solved it for me.