# How does @value in lombok work in this example

Tags: java, lombok

This is my simple class

```
@Value
public class Task {
    private static int numberOfTasks = 0;
    private int id = ++numberOfTasks;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp startTime;
    private Timestamp endTime;
}
```

Reading [the Documentation of @Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value), It says:

```
In practice, @Value is shorthand for: final @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @AllArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Getter,
```

So that means there is a AllArguConstructor. However, If I try to make the field as final, I get a compiler error that the filed is not initialised.

(though also Lombok claims to make the field as final in the case of @Value)

Could anyone help here?

This is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Which field are you trying to set as final?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I'd like all of them to be final, except the static one of course.

Comment: @DaniMesejo to be more clear, I'd like name, start time and end time to be in the constructor, while the id is assigned automatically. though all fields should be final except the static one.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce I'm using Java 11 and Lombok 1.18.12

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am using java 8 with lombok 1.18.12

Comment: Have you tried compiling not using Intellij? Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea or this https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Comment: @DaniMesejo funny enough, If I compile with maven, it works. So it is an intellij issue then.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I installed lombok plugin in interij and that helped. thank you