# Getting null values in postman while fetching data from database using springboot although data is present in database, through userId/categoryId

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to create a blog apis but Getting null values in postman while fetching data from database although data is present in database using springboot, when i am trying to get data by userId or categoryId. it's giving me null value as shown.

```
 { "postTitle": null, "postContent": null, "postImageName": null, 
"postAddedDate": null, "category": null, "user": null }
```

**// Controller Class**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    // create
    @PostMapping("/user/{userId}/category/{categoryId}/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> createPost(@RequestBody PostDto postDto, @PathVariable Integer userId,
            @PathVariable Integer categoryId) {

        PostDto createdPost = this.postService.createPost(postDto, userId, categoryId);
        return new ResponseEntity<PostDto>(createdPost, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // get post by user
    @GetMapping("/user/{userId}/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostDto>> getPostByUser(@PathVariable Integer userId) {
        List<PostDto> posts = this.postService.getPostByUser(userId);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<PostDto>>(posts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // get post by category
    @GetMapping("/category/{categoryId}/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<Set<PostDto>> getPostByCategory(@PathVariable Integer categoryId) {
        Set<PostDto> posts = this.postService.getPostByCategory(categoryId);
        return new ResponseEntity<Set<PostDto>>(posts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**//Post Entity Class**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer postId;
    private String postTitle;
    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String postContent;
    private String postImageName;
    private Date postAddedDtae;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

**//Post Dto Class**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PostDto {

    private String postTitle;
    private String postContent;
    private String postImageName;
    private Date postAddedDate;

    private CategoryDto category;

    private UserDto user;

}
```

**//Post Repo class**

```html
public interface PostRepo extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

    List<Post> findByUser(User user);

    Set<Post> findByCategory(Category category);
}
```

**//Post Service Class**

public interface PostService {

```
// create
PostDto createPost(PostDto postDto, Integer userId, Integer categoryId);

// update
Post updatePost(PostDto postDto, Integer posId);

// getAll
List<PostDto> getAllPost();

// getSinglepost
Post getPostByid(Integer PostId);

// Delete
void deletePost(Integer postId);

// getPOstByCategory
Set<PostDto> getPostByCategory(Integer categoryId);

// getAllPostByUser
List<PostDto> getPostByUser(Integer userId);

// Search Post
List<PostDto> searchPosts(String keyword);
```

}

**//Post ServiceImplmentation class**

```java
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepo postRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepo categoryRepo;

    @Override
    public PostDto createPost(PostDto postDto, Integer userId, Integer categoryId) {

        User user = this.userRepo.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "User Id", userId));

        Category category = this.categoryRepo.findById(categoryId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Category", "Category Id", categoryId));

        Post post = this.modelMapper.map(postDto, Post.class);
        post.setPostImageName("Default.png");
        post.setPostAddedDtae(new Date());
        post.setUser(user);
        post.setCategory(category);

        Post newPost = this.postRepo.save(post);
        return this.modelMapper.map(newPost, PostDto.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Post updatePost(PostDto postDto, Integer posId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PostDto> getAllPost() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Post getPostByid(Integer PostId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePost(Integer postId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Set<PostDto> getPostByCategory(Integer categoryId) {
        Category cat = this.categoryRepo.findById(categoryId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Category", "Category Id", categoryId));
        Set<Post> posts = this.postRepo.findByCategory(cat);

        Set<PostDto> postDtos = posts.stream().map((post) -> this.modelMapper.map(posts, PostDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return postDtos;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PostDto> getPostByUser(Integer userId) {
        User user = this.userRepo.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "User Id", userId));
        List<Post> posts = this.postRepo.findByUser(user);
        List<PostDto> postDtos = posts.stream().map((post) -> this.modelMapper.map(posts, PostDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return postDtos;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PostDto> searchPosts(String keyword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Please check and let me know where i am going wrong...**

Answer (score 0):

In `PostServiceImpl` change:

```java
Set<PostDto> postDtos = posts.stream().map((post) -> this.modelMapper.map(posts, PostDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

to

```java
Set postDtos = posts.stream().map((post) -> this.modelMapper.map(post, PostDto.class))
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Why would removing the type parameter from the `Set` help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem you have is about mapstruct or/and lombok. I would recommand you to check if generated mapper impl mapstruct file ModelMapperImpl looks good (you should have for every entity field an instruction for mapping with dto associated field or/and vice versa).

If this is not the case, check if `lombok`, `mapstruct` and `lombok-mapstruct-binding` dependencies are well present and configured in you `pom.xml` or build.gradle file ( [here an example for this implementation with maven](https://bootify.io/spring-data/mapstruct-with-maven-and-lombok.html) ). Also, For your IDE check if lombok is well configured ([by installing lombok plugins and enabling annotation processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea))